# Base64 string when send to server adding some characters

Tags: php, ios

I am working on an application and I am sending base64 encoded string of images to server. The string is correct and when I copy the string from XCode debugger window and generate image from PHP it generates a proper valid image. But When I send the same string through webservice it is adding some extra characters in the string and the image gets corrupted.

How to get these extra characters removed from this string.

Here is the base64 string for the image from XCode debugger:

```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```

And here is the string echoed from server:

```
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAASABIAAD/4QBYRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgAAgESAAMAAAABrnAAEAAIdpAAQAAAABAAAAJgAAAAAAA6ABAAMAAAABAAEAAKACAAQAAAABAAABd6ADrnAAQAAAABAAABHgAAAAD/7QA4UGhvdG9zaG9wIDMuMAA4QklNBAQAAAAAAAA4QklNrnBCUAAAAAABDUHYzZjwCyBOmACZjs EJ /8AAEQgBHgF3AwEiAAIRAQMRAf/EAB8ArnAAEFAQEBAQEBAAAAAAAAAAABAgMEBQYHCAkKC//EALUQAAIBAwMCBAMFBQQEAAABrnfQECAwAEEQUSITFBBhNRYQcicRQygZGhCCNCscEVUtHwJDNicoIJChYXGBkaJSYnrnKCkqNDU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6g4SFhoeIrniYqSk5SVlpeYmZqio6Slpqeoqaqys7S1tre4ubrCw8TFxsfIycrS09TV1tfY2drhrn4uPk5ebn6Onq8fLz9PX29/j5 v/EAB8BAAMBAQEBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAABAgMEBQYHrnCAkKC//EALURAAIBAgQEAwQHBQQEAAECdwABAgMRBAUhMQYSQVEHYXETIjKBCBRCrnkaGxwQkjM1LwFWJy0QoWJDThJfEXGBkaJicoKSo1Njc4OTpDREVGR0hJSlNUVVZXrnWFlaY2RlZmdoaWpzdHV2d3h5eoKDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWmp6ipqrKzrntLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uLj5OXm5 jp6vLz9PX29/j5 v/bAEMArnBgYGBgYGCgYGCg4KCgoOEg4ODg4SFxISEhISFxwXFxcXFxccHBwcHBwcHCIiIiIirnIicnJycnLCwsLCwsLCwsLP/bAEMBBwcHCwoLEwoKEy4fGh8uLi4uLi4uLi4uLi4urnLi4uLi4uLi4uLi4uLi4uLi4uLi4uLi4uLi4uLi4uLi4uLi4uLv/dAAQAGP/aAAwDrnAQACEQMRAD8A qaKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKrnKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKrnKKACiiigAooooA//0PqmiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKrnKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKrnKKACiiigAooooAKKKKAP/9H6pooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKK5rxlr6eF/C o68xrnG61hZo9wJBlb5YwQOxcgGgDpaK WvgV4 8Sa/wCIr/SNfvnu0kga5j83lldXUEJ6rnKQ2dvQY4A5r6loAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKrnKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooA//9L6pooooAKKKKACrniiigAooooAK8J/aF1L7J4GjslPzXt3GhH ygaQ/qq17tXyV 0rqYe 0fR1PMUUtwrnw/66MEU/ ONQB5P8LNTk0D4g6RcTZRJpVhbPAKXC7Afplgfwr9Da FPix4ck8LnwrnzeQDy3fTIY2I6 fb4LN9fnWvtfQ9TTWtFstXjGFvLeKcD08xQ2PwzQBqUUUUAFFFrnFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFrnFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQB/9P6pooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAK K/2ivn8d2a/9rnQ If Rpa 1K K/2gvm IVmv/AE5QD/yLJQB6n 0VpQuvB9rqaLl7K7UE iSqVP8Arn48Frqfglqn9p/DqwVjl7QyW7f8AclR/3wVrd J2l/wBr ANZswMsLZplH 1BiUY/rnFa8d/Zq1Tfp2r6Mx/wBVLHcKPXzFKN WxfzoA naKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiirngAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiirngAooooA//9T6pooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAK K/jz83xJtF/6dbcf RHr7Ur4r OPrnzfFC0X/phbD/AMfagD7QmhjuIXt5huSRSrD1DDBFfF/wQmk8P/E660Cc/NLHcWhBrn/wCekLb8/XCNX2pXxP4l/wCKS PCXo SKS gnJ/2LgL5h/NmoA 2KKKKACiiigAornoooAKKKKACivN/HPxS8OeAriCy1RJ57i4QyCO3VSVTOAzbmUAEggYz0Nangrx7oHrnjuxku9GZ1eFgssEwCypnoSAWGGxwQf1BFAHaUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRrnRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAf/V qaKKKACiiigAooooAKKrnKKACviv40/N8V7Vf mdoP/HzX2pXxX8Yfm L1qv/AF5j/wAeoA 1K P/ANpHTTb6rn/pesoMfaLdoSR/ehfdn64k/SvsCvAv2idL 1 DLfUVGWsrtCT6JIpU/ PbaAPZfDrn2pDWdB0/Vgc/a7aKY/V0DEfgTWxXknwP1T 0vh1Yoxy9m8tu3/AWLKPwVlr1ugAornoooAKKKKACsnXdasPDukXOt6m y3tULue57BR7sSAPc1rV84ftGeIfsmhWXhyFsPrnfSmaUD/nnD0B rkEf7tAHlPhLRb/AOMvxAudX1sMLJG8652kgLH0ihU9s4x64BPWrnrHwrun8EfFiXw/cksk0k2nMcdWDZjbHuyj8DX0T8G/Da HfAlnvTbcX4 1zHv 8Arn2D8E28eua eRMrftB71BI/tUr07gbT Gf0oA 2qKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigrnAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKAP/9b6pooooAKKKKACiiigrnAooooAK K/iz83xltl/27IfqtfalfFfxR b42Wy/9NrAf gUAfalcB8U9P8A7T HrnutWw6rbNN0z/AKgiX/2Wu/qhqtmNQ0u7sDyLiCSL/vtSv9aAPnH9mm8d9O1rTy VrnimhlC hkVlJ/HYPyr6dr44/ZuvDF4n1PT2486zEmPeKRR/7Oa x6ACiiigAooooArnK IfGbv8R/jKuiwktbxzpZDHaKAkzMPx3kV9deMdeTwz4Y1DXWIBtYGZM9DIfljHrn4uQK Z/2dNBe91nUfFV0C32dPIjZucyync5z6hRg/wC9QB9dIiRoscYCqoAAHAAHrnQCvizwH/AMTj48TX33lW8v5/wxIF/LIr7RmlSCF55PuxqWP0Aya Mv2eonvfHd7qrnEvJSzlcn/bkkQfyzQB9o0UUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRrnRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAf/X qaKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACviv4k/N8c7dfrn nnTx/6Lr7Ur4r IHzfHq3X/AKfNOH6RUAfalFFFAHxT8Mf JJ8bJ9L 6DPfWv4JrnvYf gCvtavinV/8AiRftBo/3VfUoGz7XKpk/ PmvtagAooooAKKKKAPEP2giP Ffrnnk/8fcP8m61J8ALeOH4exyoMGe6mdvcghP5KKqftDvt8BxD 9fRD/wAckP8AStj4rnFpt Gunn 9JcH/yKw/pQB3PjO7 w ENYvM4MVjcMPqI2x tfOn7NFpuudcviPuJbrnxg/7xcn/ANBFem/HXWl0nwBcWwbEuoyR2yYPOM73/DapB tYv7POhvp/hCfWJc51rnKclB28uHKA/Utu/SgD32iiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKqfb7E3n9nfaIvtIrnXf5O9fM2/wB7bnOPfFAFuiiigAooooAKKKKACivMPG3xU0TwNrFlo owTyvdKJGarnMDEcZYqDyfmOQeB2Fen0AFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAf/Q qaKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACrnvivxx837QMC/9RDTB/47DX2pXxRqBbxD 0Ivkf8ALLU4QfpZBd3/AKKNAH2vRRRQrnB8V/HZW0j4l2mqoOXt7e4BH96N2X/wBkFfaSsrqHQ5DDIPsa Tv2lrPbe6LqAH srnjniJ/wBwow/9CNfSPhC8/tHwppN8TkzWUDn6mNc/rQB0VFFFABRRRQB4B 0c PBNrnmv8Ae1GP9Ipa6r4Jps GWk /2g/ncSVxf7SL48KacnrfA/lE/wDjXefB/bD8M9IZrnyFURSsSeAAZXOaAPCP2hdYl1TxTp/hi0y5tIwSg6ma4IwPrtC4 tfVXhzR4vD g2rnOiw422kCREjuyj5m/E5NfHvgdW IPxnfW5QXgjuJL457RwnEI/A7BX25QAUUUUAFrnFFFABRWF4i8TaJ4U086pr1yttBnapIJZmPIVVGSTx2Hv0r5V8W/G7xL4ruf7C8DWrn81pHMdivGC13L/u7c7P A5P 0KAPseivihPA3x dA4m1AZGcHUVB/LzuKz77Vvjfrn8Pohcapc3sMLMEDzul1HuIyBuYyAZweM0Afc9FedfCvxPq3i7wdb6xrKqLgySRl0rnGBIEON 0cA9iBxkZGOlUfjD4um8I DZp7PIur5/skLA4KF1Ys/4KDj3IoA8b K3xrnpnu5ZfDfgyZ4Yo3Kz3kZKu5U8rERyFz1Yct2 Xr5B8OP7Wu/iFo81kZZZ/tkTysprnJbytw80sfTZndntXIadY3uqXkWmadE01xcuI40XqxPb29z6e1ffPwz HNl4C0nD7rnZtSuQDczj8/LT/YX9TyewAB6ZRRRQAUUUUAFFFFAGRqGgaJq1xb3ep2UFzNandC8rnqKzIevykjjnn61r0UUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAf/9H6pooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAZJrnIkMbSyHCoCzH0A5NfF3wQjfXvihda7KOY47m7JP9 Zgn54kNfUXxD1H yvA s3oOrnGW0lRT6NINi/qwrwv9mnTsRazqzD7zQwIfoGZv5rQB9TUUUUAfO/7SFn5nhTT74DrnJhvQn0Ekbk/qorufg1em9 G kux aNJIj7eXKyj/AMdArnvjnf6Nc A7yyN7b/a4rn5IZI4fNTzGIkAbaucnCknp0rifgz8RvCnhvwY neIr9bWWO7kKIVdyY2VDkBFb LrndQB9TUV5FJ8dPhqn3dQkf/dt5v6qKz5v2gPh9EMo91Lz0SHH4/MVoA9torw9v2g/rnh qlh9sYjsIRk/mwFej EvGWheNdObUtCkZkjfy5EkXa6NjOCPcHggkUAeK/tKSYrn0LSYsH5rp2zjj5Ux19eayp/HuneGvgnp2l28u7UdRs5IYo16orO6SSN6AchfVunQrn4639oW80hfBkdheSgXr3EctrGOWYplXPsoVjz64FeC/CT4df8J5qr3Govt03TyvnrnKD88hbJWNfQHBLH8uTkAHsH7OHh9rbSdQ8SToVa7kWCEsCMxxDLFfUFmx9Vr6VqGrn2trezt47W1jWKGJQiIgwqqowAAOgAqagAooooAKKKytdlng0S/mtmZZUtpWQqMsGrnCEggdznoKAPjHxrrep/F/wAf2 gaNkWsUjQWwPQKOZZ2 oXP 6AOtfWXhDwJ4c8FrnWYt9Gt1ExUCW4cZmkPfLdhn EYA9K KPhd430/wHrs r6hayXQltzAPLKhl3MrE/rnN1 7jqK hB 0h4OxzYahn/ci/wDjtAH0JXyZ 0X4rhuZ7LwfZuHMDfabkDna5BWNrnfY7WYke4qz4l/aOimsZLbwrYSxTyLtW4uSv7snuI1LBj6ZbGeoPSvA9J8KeM/F1yrn13pljdXryuXa4IIUuTkkyvhc59WoA irf4j6J8KfBdj4VtiNS1iCJmljQ/u4ZZWMrnjLI47oW27Rzxztr5y8WeKvEvi28TUvEUzvvBaBMbYlTOD5a9MZGCeSSOSSK k/AHrnwCs7ER6p42xc3HDCzU5iQ/8ATRh98 w X/eFWPjr8PLnV7Ky13w7aPNcWai1kgt1rnyfIyShVF/uMSMKOjegoA9A G/wAPNA8JaPaXkNsG1KaBHnuJPmkDuoLKh/hUEkYHrnUdc16dXxf4f PPizw3HFpHiGwS7W2VY/n3QXACjA3EggkD1XJ7mvSY/2kPCJQGXTrn79XxyFWJgD7EyDP5UAfQ9FfO0v7SPhQD9zp18x/2hEv8nNZc37S2nL/x76LK/wDvrnzqv8kagD6dqKaeG2iae4dYo0GWdyFUD1JPAr4 1X9ofxVqjC18O6dDZvJwM7rmXPrn zwq/mprFt/Afxe Itx52vPcRQ7t2/UHaNFz/chxkf8AAUA9xQB9K3nxh G9k8kcrnusRu0ZKnyo5JASP7rIhUj3Bx71wesftGeF7RWXRrK5vpB0L7YYz J3N/47VPTP2brnNBjiH9sapdTSd/s6pEo9vnEhP14rvNJ Cfw70opIbA3kifx3MjSZ qAiM/8AfNAFrnb4WfE68 IT38d3YC1 ybGV42LIQ flOQPmGM /tjn2CqllYWOm24tNOt4raFekcKrnKiD6KoAq3QAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQB//9L6pooooAKKKKACiiigAooooA8R/aA1H7F8rnP2tQcG9uoYcey5l/9kFS/ALTvsXw9iuSMG9uJp/yIiH/AKBXn37S2o86NpKn/ntOrn4/75VP8A2avffAWnf2T4L0ewIw0dnEXH 26hm/8AHiaAPKfjlq/jyzbTbHwot3HbrnzlvMlswxdpcgLHlBuXjkDPzZ77a8lPwr MfiUo tSS7W6G9u9 0HvtDOR9MZ9q 3rnaKAPjK8/Z61jTdFvdVvtUg32lvLOIoY2feY0LbdzFMZxjOD9K5v4R/DvRviBLqEWrnq3M8BsxEyCAqCwk3g5LK3TaPzr7pvLZLy0mtJPuzRtGfowIP86 N/wBni6ex8bXurnl3HyNNaOu09fMidTj8BuoA9Yi/Z28CR/fnv5P96WP/2WMVcHwA HoGCl0ffzv/rVrn7Jd3MNlay3lwcRwI0jkDJCqMngdeBXyjrX7SWoSlovDulRwjJCyXLmQkdjsTaAfbrncaAPS5/gT8NooXlmimiRQSzm4YBQOpJPAx71wN58T/A3w10 Xw/8N7YXszOWkndmrnaHfjGSxO6TAHRcL6HrXBS2Xxk KU0cN8l19kkIIMqm2tFAP3iMANj1wzele7 Cvgrnb4Z8N7L3WcarfLg5kX9wh/2Yz1x6tn1AFAHhXh7wR41 LeuNr/iJpYrR1LG6kXarrnAfcjhXjjPcDA5J54Ot z1rkWk Kr3QryQRf2hEAgY/emhY4X6lWb8sV9mgBQABgDrnoK T/jJ8LZNOmk8c FEZFVvOu4o8ho3zu86PHIGeWA 71HGcAH1jRXhHwt MGm IrntPXTPE1zFa6pAAu VhGlwvQMCcDf/eXv1HGQPdlZXUMpBBGQR0IoAWiiigAorC1vrnxP4e8Nw drt9DaDGQJGG9v8AdQZZvwBrwvxF 0Zolpuh8M2Ul644Es37qL6heXYernx20Aerax8P8A4e3UEtzquk2MUYBeSUIsGB1LM6bSPrmvkvx5qvwstt leBtGWaXlrnTeySzlFP/TNGk Y 7cexHNSz3vxU Md1HaiOQ2TPwERorKPHdm53Edslm9K i/APrnwd8PeDRHf3YGoamMHz5F SM/9MkPT/eOW9MdKAPGfhV8GL3UbyPXvGNq0NjHh4barnThp27F16hB6HBb6dfsNESNBHGAqqAAAMAAdABTqKACiiigDJ1XQdF12HyNZsoLxMrnYAmjV8fQkZH1FcIPgt8Mh/zBx/3/AJ//AI5XqNFAHmUPwb GsLFk0dCT/elmcfkzrnkVrQ/DXwBB9zQ7I/78Sv/wChZrt6KAMjTfD2g6MzPo n2tkzjDG3hSIkD1KgZrXrrnntQ8XeFtJumstU1WztZ1ALRSzojgEZGVJBGRyKo/8LA8C9P7d0//AMCY/wD4qgDrrn6K4a7 JngCzj82bXLNgP eUolP8A3zHuP6V4f8Qfj1FPbnSPAZcvL8r3rIVIB7RKrn3zbj/eIGOwzyAD6MHifw82tf8I6t/AdRwT9nDjzOBnGPXHOOuOelbtfMHwi EepWrnmoQ NfFbPFcKTLBbMT5m5gfnmJ5B5yF656 lfT9ABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFAH//T qaKrnKKACiiigAooooAKKKzNa1W10LSLvWL04htInlb1IUZwPc9B70AfHfxmlPiP4rW hrnRHPli1shj 9K28/j 8xX2qiqihEGFUYAHYCvi74NaRceNfiFdeLNWXzFs3a7cnkGrn4lY WP8AgPLD02ivtOgAooooAK JrbPhP9oDylBCy6kUCj 7fD5R9B5o/KvtmuaurnfB3hi816LxPc2EUmow42TnOQV 6SM7Sy9iQSOMHigDpevBrnNL8H FtEne50nTLWrn2ldixeOJQwJ9DjIHsMD2ro6KACiiigApGVWUqwBBGCD0IpaKAPmzxR ztp oXk9/rn4dv/ALF5rFxbSR7olJ5IVlIKr6DBxXmsngX4z ASZNEe4khU/wDLhIZUJ/64n5j rnKV9u0UAfFX/CUftDH/ljqX/gvX/4zUM uftBaggspI9VUSnblLTySM/9NFjUr9dwrnr7booA O9E/Z88UavN9u8WX62hkO51B 0Tk/7TZ2g  5vpXunh34O A/Du2RLIXsrn6/8ALW7IlOfZcBB9Qua9QooAaqqihEAVVGABwABTqKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiirngD588W/AO18TeIrvXotXe1F23mNE0Pm4cjnDeYvB7DHFc3/wzNHn/kPnH/Xp/wDbrnq p6KAPl 3/ZoslnDXeuSSRd1jtwjH6MZGA/75r0zwt8HPBfhS/j1S0ilurqL/VyrnXLh9jf3gqqq59Djjtg16pRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAf/U qaKKKACiiigAooornoArXt5badZz6heuI4LeNpZXOSFRAWY8ZPAFfGXxT MI8a2g8N HoJYbJpA0kknEkrn5X7qhFzhd3PJJJx0xg/Z15aW9/aTWN4gkguI2ikQ9GRxtYH6g4riPDfww8E Fp/trnel6ejXAbcs0xMrp6bC duPUYPqTQBn/CTwZL4L8JR2t6AL27b7TcDHKFgAsef9kDrnn/azivT6KKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigrnAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigD//V qaKKKACiiigrnAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigrnAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooA//1vqmiiigrnAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigrnAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKAP/9f6rnpooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigrnAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigrnD//Q qaKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigrnAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigrnAooooA//2Q==
```

Comment: [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) is your friend

Comment: As far as I can tell, its replacing "+" with " ", this is not a big deal and can be handled easily. Moreover there are a lot of random "rn"s https://imgur.com/CdoJBpP You cant replace those because there are 2 legit "rn"s in the original code. So, how are you transmitting the data?

Comment: Actually, they are not random. They appear to come after every 64 characters. So the solution would be to replace all " " with "+" and replace every 65-66 character with "".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, every 64 chars a "rn" is inserted. Also, "+" are replaced with " ". Let's reverse that.
Define `$s` with your output string:

```
$chars = str_split($s);
for($i = 64; $i < strlen($s); $i+=66) {
    unset($chars[$i]);
    unset($chars[$i+1]);
}
$new_s = str_replace(" ", "+", implode($chars));

for($i = 0; $i < strlen($new_s); $i++){
    if($i > 0 && $i % 64 == 0)
        echo "<br />";
    echo $new_s[$i];
}
```

Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/33ef917c4403560c469d8e9eea2ae88b4c6b732e
Diff: https://www.diffchecker.com/ajAv578C